# How to combine vega-lite legends when including a rule mark in a separate layer?

Tags: legend, vega-lite

I have a [vega-lite visualization](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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) that uses `shape` and `color` as dimensions with the same field.

Typically the shape and color legends are merged into a single legend, however if I add a layer with a `rule` mark, the legends get split into two.

How do I keep the legends combined while keeping the rule mark in a separate layer?

Update: I also see a warning saying:

> shape dropped as it is incompatible with "rule".

though I'm not sure what I should do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "layer": [
    {
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"},
        "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal"},
        "shape": {"field": "c", "type": "nominal", "sort": {"field": "a"}},
        "color": {"field": "c", "type": "nominal", "sort": {"field": "a"}}
      },
      "mark": "point"
    },
    {
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "a"},
        "opacity": {
          "condition": {"param": "hover", "value": 0.3, "empty": false},
          "value": 0
        }
      },
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "hover",
          "select": {
            "nearest": true,
            "fields": ["a"],
            "on": "mouseover",
            "type": "point"
          }
        }
      ],
      "mark": {"stroke": "#888", "type": "rule", "point": false}
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 28, "c": "Blue"},
      {"a": "B", "b": 55, "c": "Yellow"},
      {"a": "C", "b": 43, "c": "Red"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Just so I understand correctly. The trick is to put the shape and color into the `y` layer's encoding.

Comment: Yes - encodings which are shared are unioned.